# Azure oauth v2.0 interaction_required error with trusted ip and MFA

Tags: azure, oauth-2.0, azure-ad-graph-api, multi-factor-authentication

I have set up this Azure AD authentication workflow on my web server :

**1 -** The user login from this url :

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant_id}/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?
    client_id={client_id}
    &redirect_uri=https://example.com/callback
    &scope=openid%20https%3A%2F%2Fgraph.windows.net%2Fuser.read
    &response_mode=query
    &response_type=code
```

**2 -**  (MFA) The user submit a form with a code received on its phone

**3 -** The user is redirected to `https://example.com/callback?code={azure_given_code}`

**4 -** I exchange the `{azure_given_code}` for a token via the following POST request **server side** :

```
POST https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant_id}/oauth2/token

{
    "client_id": "{client_id}",
    "client_secret": "{client_secret}",
    "code": "{azure_given_code}",
    "grant_type": "authorization_code",
    "redirect_uri": "https://example.com/callback"
}
```

**5 -** I receive an access token and can retrieve the logged-in user from this url, again, **server side** :

```
https://graph.windows.net/me?api-version=1.6
```

I added our office ip address to the trusted ip list so that users can bypass MFA when connecting from our network.

Everything works fine **if I am doing this workflow outside of the office network** (from an untrusted ip that triggers MFA).
But with my office ip, the step 2 is bypassed (as expected) and at step 3 I get the following error :

```
{
    "error": "interaction_required",
    "error_description": "AADSTS50076: Due to a configuration change made by your administrator, or because you moved to a new location, you must use multi-factor authentication to access …",     "error_codes": [50076],
    "timestamp": "2020-03-13 12:54:58Z",
    "trace_id": '...'
}
```

**What am I missing here to have this workflow working in both case (from a trusted and untrusted ip) ?**

I am really stuck with this issue, many thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how I solved my problem.

When the user is redirected to the login url `https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant_id}/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?...` **his IP is used** to determine whether or not he can bypass the MFA according to trusted ip rules.

Then when the `azure_given_code` is retrieved, the request for the token is made **server side**, using the **server IP** which is the cause of the error (server IP is not a trusted one).

Doing the `POST https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant_id}/oauth2/token` client side did solve the issue since the IP used for the request is a trusted one.

**EDIT**

In this case, you should not expose your `client_secret` front-side. You should configure your app in azure as a single-page application platform.

Comment: Doing the POST client side will expose the {client_secret} and that makes your solution vulnerable.

Comment: The {client_secret} is not required to exchange the code for a token in single page app, which is the configuration I am using. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-auth-code-flow#request-an-access-token-with-a-client_secret